# msxml3.dll: The download of the specified resource has failed -When using XMLHTTP

Tags: xmlhttprequest, msxml

I have a java script code snippet where i am making an XMLHTTP request to a remote server page. The below is my code

```
    var objXMLdom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XmlDOM")
    var objXMLRecdom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XmlDOM")
    objXMLdom.async = false
    var objXMLRoot = objXMLdom.createElement("root");           
    objXMLdom.documentElement = objXMLRoot;

    objXMLRoot.setAttribute("strWoCode",id);
    var objXMLHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    strHTTP = "getDataResponse.aspx?wocode="+strWoCode+"&mode="report";     
    objXMLHttp.open("POST",strHTTP,false)
    objXMLHttp.send(objXMLdom);
```

When the last line (send()) is executing,I am getting an error like " msxml3.dll: The download of the specified resource has failed." . My development machine is running on Win XP SP 2

Can anyone help to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your strHTTP variable.  It needs to contain the full URL.  Also, don't forget to encode your strWoCode variable to prevent URL injection.

```
strHttp = "http://www.mywebsite.com/getDataResponse.aspx?";
strHTTP = strHTTP + "wocode="+encodeURIComponent(strWoCode)+"&mode="report";
```